# How to get the document inside a field out after "group by" in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The documents I work on are like this:

```
{
    "id" : "98syf87erfw8n"
    "foo" : { "objectid" : "39", "stuff" : "65" },
    "yearpublished" : "1979",
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This is the query I used:

```
db.foobar.aggregate([
    { $group : {
        _id : '$yearpublished',
        myItem: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }}
])
```

The final output is in the form:

```
{
    { "_id" : "1923", "myItem" : {
                            "id" : "98syf87erfw8n",
                            "foo" : { "objectid" : "39", "stuff" : "65" },
                            "yearpublished" : "1979"
                        }
    }, 
    { "_id" : "1453", "myItem" : {
                            "id" : "88888888888",
                            "foo" : { "objectid" : "394", "stuff" : "55" },
                            "yearpublished" : "1453"
                            "author" : "Ravi Kiran"
                        }
    }
};
```

But I want the output as:

```
{
    "id" : "98syf87erfw8n",
    "foo" : { "objectid" : "39", "stuff" : "65" },
    "yearpublished" : "1979"
},
{
    "id" : "88888888888",
    "foo" : { "objectid" : "394", "stuff" : "55" },
    "yearpublished" : "1453",
    "author" : "Ravi Kiran"
}
```

This means I want to get those documents inside the field `myItem` out.
How can I do that?

Comment: since you are grouping by yearpublished, that can result in multiple `id` matching the `yearpublished`.  Should the `id` in the output be an array?

Comment: Of all those multiple documents, I'm taking the first one only usign "$first"

Comment: You can use the `$replaceRoot` stage.

Comment: Can you answer on how to write the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$replaceRoot`

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g2kndUoTmoV)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$myItem"
  }
})
```

There are syntax errors in your output.

`"id" : 98syf87erfw8n`, is invalid.

It should be `"id" : "98syf87erfw8n"`, Note the quotes

There is comma missing after `yearPublished` in the second object.

Answer (score 0):

One more project stage after the $group can do the job:

```
{
 $project: {
  yearpublished: "$myItem.yearpublished",
  foo: "$myItem.foo",
  id: "$myItem.id",
  _id: 0
 }
}
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t_mRueCS8hn)

Comment: the number of fields are not fixed. One document may contain 5 fields, another may contain one extra field.

Comment: for this case I see @Gibbs provided better solution below ...